# Java Doc to PDF Convertor

Tags: java, pdf, doc

I'm looking for a solution in my "JAVA" project to convert documents (including MS-word files) to PDF. I already used OpenOffice+JodConvertor but the result most of the time is not as good as I expect. Does anyone knows a framwork or a solution rather OpenOffice?

Best

Comment: you want to do the conversion programmatically using Java APIS, is that the question?

Comment: Try one of online Rest Api for Word to Pdf conversions http://www.convertapi.com

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this.
http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Neither Apache POI,nor PDFBox create PDF From Documents. POI only parses MS-word documents and PDFBox only parses PDF documents. That I dont' need! I need an API to convert MS-Word to PDF from Java code.